# Help identifying components on Sony PS Vita 2000 motherboard

Tags: identification, components, motherboard

I need help identifying 2 components from a Sony PS Vita 2000 motherboard. One is a chip with code AG8 only (has 5 pins each side). The other one is like a 4 pin resistor. No resistance between 2 pins and high resistance to the other 2.

[image: Photo of PCB]

Comment: they appear to have something to do with what I assume is a USB connector right next to them.

Comment: why do you need to identify those components?

Comment: It looks like the smaller one is a common mode choke for the USB data pins, and the larger one is an ESD protection device for USB data pins.

Comment: Thank you, the ag8 chip is shorting and, as a result, console is not charging and usb not working. Dont know where  to identify and buy those components

Comment: Thank you all for you help. So the part bellow is, indeed a common choke. The chip, based on my search, because I couldn't find it by code, is a ts3usba225rutr UQFN-12 lqr lq7 chip

Comment: @JoãoCosta I understand this is an old question but did you ever find out for certain what the part was (the chip specifically)? Did you confirm the chip was the part you suggested in your comment? I Have a vita with failed USB and suspect this chip my have failed.

Comment: Hi, in my case was that chip. Replaced it with one from a donor board and worked

Comment: @JoãoCosta thanks for the response! Sounds promising, I’d much rather repair this than replace it. I’ll try the part you suggested though as finding a parts machine is proving very difficult in my area.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for this part too and since google keeps showing this when looking for this component, the part number for that larger IC in a PS Vita Model 1000 is: TS3USB31RSER
It is a "High-Speed USB 2.0 (480-Mbps) 1-Port Switch With Single Enable" from Texas Instruments in a UQFN 8 package.

For the Vita 2000, it's most like their newer "TUSB213" model USB 2.0 Redriver with a VQFN 14 package. It might not be, because that looks like a 12 pin IC, but it's the closest I can find and likely is a drop-in replacement.